# Adding too many plugins/extensions to a browser, affect browsing speed?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, performance-tuning

I am using extensions added from the official websites like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/extensions/ , https://chrome.google.com/webstore. If the answer is Yes, is there any way to find out which plugin causing trouble.

Question related to 'browsing speed': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432915/does-browsing-speed-depend-on-the-browser  is not talking about browser plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hit SHIFT + ESC in chrome to get the chrome task manager. Then you can see what extensions are using what resources.

Some extensions need to run pre-page load such as Ad-Blockers, several of these will case a delay every time you click a link.

Answer (score 1):

Every extension that you add into a browser will take up memory. You can check how much memory an add-on is using in Firefox by using [about:addons-memory](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/about-addons-memory/).

[image: about:addons-memory]
 To use it, you will have to go to about:addons-memory or about:about and navigate to about:addons-memory. This should let you know how much memory each add-on is using, but it will omit some things like tabs.